# XMLHttpRequest stream crashing when uploading large files (~1 GB)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, stream, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make an online file manager for another project with friends, and when uploading files bigger than 1GB, the process either crashes (firefox), or succeeds but the received file weighs 0 bytes (chromium).

JS:

```
    function uploadFile(fileInputId, fileIndex) {
        //send file name
        try {
            var fileName = document.getElementById('fileUploader').files[0].name;
        }
        catch {
            document.getElementById('uploadStatus').innerHTML = `<font color="red">Mettre un fichier serait une bonne idée.</font>`;
            return false;
        }
        document.cookie = 'fname=' + fileName;

        //take file from input
        const file = document.getElementById(fileInputId).files[fileIndex];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        reader.onloadend = function(event) {
            ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            //send data
            ajax.open("POST", 'uploader.php', true);

            //all browser supported sendAsBinary
            XMLHttpRequest.prototype.mySendAsBinary = function(text) {
                var data = new ArrayBuffer(text.length);
                var ui8a = new Uint8Array(data, 0)
                for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) ui8a[i] = (text.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);

                if (typeof window.Blob == "function") {
                    var blob = new Blob([data]);
                }else {
                    var bb = new (window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder)();
                    bb.append(data);
                    var blob = bb.getBlob();
                }

                this.send(blob);
            }
            //track progress
            var eventSource = ajax.upload || ajax;
            eventSource.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
                //percentage
                var position = e.position || e.loaded;
                var total = e.totalSize || e.total;
                var percentage = Math.round((position/total)*100);

                document.getElementById('uploadStatus').innerHTML = `${percentage}%`;
            });

            ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('uploadStatus').innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }

            ajax.mySendAsBinary(event.target.result);
        }

    }
```

PHP:

```
//mysql login
$conn = new PDO([Redacted]);

//file info
$fileName = $_COOKIE['fname'];
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;
$fileNameRaw = explode('.', $fileName)[0]; //file name with no extension
$tempFilePath = $targetDir.$fileNameRaw.'.tmp';
if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
    echo '<font color="red">Un fichier du même nom existe déjà.</font>';
    exit();
}

//read from stream
$inputHandler = fopen('php://input', 'r');
//create temp file to store data from stream
$fileHandler = fopen($tempFilePath, 'w+');

//store data from stream
while (true) {
    $buffer = fgets($inputHandler, 4096);
    if (strlen($buffer) == 0) {
        fclose($inputHandler);
        fclose($fileHandler);
        break;
    }

    fwrite($fileHandler, $buffer);
}

//when finished
rename($tempFilePath, $targetFile);
chmod($targetFile, 0777);
echo 'Fichier envoyé avec succès !';
$bddInsert = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO files(nom, chemin) VALUES(?,?)');
$bddInsert->execute(array($fileName, $targetFile));
```

in my php.ini,
max_execution_time is set to 0
max_input_time to -1
and my post max and upload max sizes are at 4G

I'm using apache2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be reading the file with the fileReader if you don't need it.

Just send the file (blob) directly to your ajax request and avoid the FileReader

```
function uploadFile (fileInputId, fileIndex) {
  // Send file name
  try {
      var fileName = document.getElementById('fileUploader').files[0].name;
  }
  catch {
      document.getElementById('uploadStatus').innerHTML = `<font color="red">Mettre un fichier serait une bonne idée.</font>`;
      return false;
  }
  document.cookie = 'fname=' + fileName;

  // Take file from input
  const file = document.getElementById(fileInputId).files[fileIndex];
  const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // send data
  ajax.open("POST", 'uploader.php', true);

  // track progress
  ajax.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    // percentage
    var position = e.position || e.loaded;
    var total = e.totalSize || e.total;
    var percentage = Math.round((position/total)*100);

    document.getElementById('uploadStatus').innerHTML = `${percentage}%`;
  });

  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('uploadStatus').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }

  ajax.send(file)
}
```

Comment: Isn't it all stored in memory at the same time if I do that ?
I'm currently trying another approach involving promises carrying parts of the file.

Edit: it worked though, I'm just worried for when 10GB files will come...

Comment: You don't need to worry about that as the browser will take care of piping the file to the network and read the file content as needed one part at the time. Files & Blob are nothing more than a references point to where the data is located. When you used the FileReader you read all of the content into the memory before even sending it to the server

Comment: Even if you slice the file into parts like `file.slice(0, 1024)` then you won't allocate 1024 byte into the RAM, the only thing you have done is taking the old blob as a references point and changed the start/end position of where it should read content from